# Asterisk ask confirmation to connect after dial like followme

Tags: asterisk, agi

How to implement followme like feature in dial command.

Example:

`incoming call -> 
Presses 1 -> 
dial 100 -> 
100 answer -> 
100 hear the voice press 1 to take the call, press 2 disconnect. -> 
press 1 both will talk, press 2 100 will disconnect.`

Please explain how to implement in `Asterisk 11.16.0`.

Comment: Please show us what you've done so far in your attempt to build this, and I'll be happy to help fix it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try  add M(privacy-mgr) to dialout param(in Settings).

If that not working for you, you can write your own custom privacy macro and put it for dialout.

You can see more examples on this page http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+Dial

As other option(freepbx way) you can create custom extension, put on it followme and setup on press  dial that extension

Answer (score 0):

If using the freepbx gui, do this:

1. Create a ring group and add the extensions you want to ring.
2. Add your cellphone to the ring group and append a # at the end of the number (ie.   14085551212#   )
3. Scroll down to "confirm call" and enable option
4. Save and Apply

When Freepbx reloads, test and it should work (I'm on Freepbx 13-12).

Optional:  I've even recorded a short announcement for use under "Remote Announce" so that I know to answer with my accounting hat, or support hat, etc.